# Collider2D.IsTouching(otherCollider) not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So for some reason the "rWallCollider.IsTouching(lWallCollider)" condition isn't responding. I had this same problem in the same project, but I can't recall what I did to fix it...  I've assigned the colliders btw.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    bool gameHasEnded = false;
    public Collider2D rWallCollider;
    public Collider2D lWallCollider;


    void Update()
    {
        if (rWallCollider.IsTouching(lWallCollider))
        {
            EndGame();
        }
    }

    public void EndGame ()
    {
        if (gameHasEnded == false)
        {
            gameHasEnded = true;
            Debug.Log("End game!");
        }
    }

}
```

Thank you for taking the time!

Comment: Please also share some details on what these colliders are. (type of colliders, configuration parameters, position when they should be touching, but the effect doesn't trigger, etc.)

Comment: I'm guessing you've forgotten to add rigidbody to one or both of the objects?